# trigger jquery event every time ember renders or rerenders

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, ember.js, bind

I need to run a function after every ember.js view render. My initial thought was to run my function once the page was ready but any view changes are not affected by the DOM manipulation in my function. Is there a way I can bind to an event (or cause a trigger) every time ember either renders a view or re-renders a view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could hook into `didInsertElement` and do there all your DOM manipulations:

For example:

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, 'processChildElements');
  },

  processChildElements: function() {
    // do here any DOM manipulatins
  }
});
```

### Edit in response to your last comment

If you don't want to hook into `didInsertElement` on a per view basis, you can always dig deeper into the framework and `reopen` the [`Ember.View`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html) class, and hook into the `render` function, then after calling `this._super(buffer);` so that the view can do it's job, or even intercept the `renderBuffer` you place there your custom code:

```
Ember.View.reopen({
  render: function(buffer) {
    this._super(buffer);
    // do funny stuff ...
    console.log(this.get('elementId'));
  }
});
```

See [here](http://jsbin.com/eyuheq/11/edit) for an example (check the console).

Hope it helps.

Comment: You're the fastest :)

Comment: I thought about didInsertElement, but it's a per view thing, and I want my function to run on all instances of a render - irrespective of view. Also; won't a didInsertElement run on the element's insertion rather than render? meaning that if a view re-renders (like toggling a tab to change views, for example) then my function won't run? I'm not sure I have a sound understanding of ember yet, btw!

Comment: @user1019085, see my last edit, I included a different approach, maybe this fit's more your use case.

Comment: Fantastic! Exactly what I needed! had to combine it with some messy setTimeout delays though, as it does seem to run my function before finishing the ember render but there's no big trouble with that - just needed it as a trigger really. Thanks!